# Is there a word 'uptrending'?

Tags: is-it-a-word

Exactly as the title states: Is there a word 'uptrending'? Wikipedia suggests it is, however, Word marks it as a mistake.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be helpful if you could supply links to what you reference.

Comment: Never trust Word (or any word processor). Have you checked an online dictionary for *uptrend*?

Comment: There is no reference to 'uptrending' in the OED http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=uptrending&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch but a number of websites incorporate the word into their URL.

Comment: Wikipedia? or Wiktionary? People just make up stuff there.

Comment: I don's see why you can't turn *uptrend* into its adjectival form. It should be easily understood. Of course, some people will insist that if it's not in a dictionary, then it's no a word.

Comment: I can't find 'uptrend' as a verb listed in a more reputable dictionary, but doubtless it will be at some point in the future.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're right. I would probably risk turning it into an adjective for casual writing.

Comment: It's one of those terms that is uptrending.

Comment: @Mitch or as Trump might say "The very dishonest fake Wikipedia"

Comment: In the immortal words of Bucky Katt, "*You can wordify anything if you just verb it.*"

Answer (score 13):

*Uptrend* as a noun first appears in written sources [1940–45](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/uptrend), while a business journal of 1946 discusses [uptrending, downtrending, and trendless markets,](https://books.google.de/books?id=MdxPAQAAMAAJ&q=%22uptrending%22&dq=%22uptrending%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDupuaw9XYAhUKlSwKHSczBh4Q6AEIITAB) and an issue of *Business Week* in 1950 speaks of [uptrending profits](https://books.google.de/books?id=_6QiAQAAMAAJ&q=%22uptrending%22&dq=%22uptrending%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDupuaw9XYAhUKlSwKHSczBh4Q6AEILTAE).

These sources suggest that *uptrending* belongs to the jargon of business and finance with little reason to escape into general use. Its hypothetical infinitive, **to uptrend*, is already occupied by *to trend up[ward]*, so it was never coined. Beyond the usual boundary enforcing function of jargon for a financial elite, why the American business mind would prefer *uptrending stocks* to *stocks trending upward* is lost in the mist of time.

An [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uptrending&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuptrending%3B%2Cc0) shows, well, a sharp uptrend of *uptrending* beginning in the 1990s, suggesting that the word is finding a less specialized use.

Comment: Interesting. [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uptrending%2C+trending&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuptrending%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrending%3B%2Cc0) also shows that *'trending'* is 100x more common than *'uptrending'*. I agree that it seems unnecessary since *'trending upwards'* already says that.

Comment: @smci But “uptrending” is shorter than “trending upwards”. There are _thousands_ of perfectly common English words that you would apparently claim are unnecessary since the same concept can be expressed using several other words. Just in my first sentence, “shorter” could be “less long” — is “shorter” unnecessary?

Comment: @MikeScott: but 'shorter' is very common (also faster to utter than 'less long'). For most of us who aren't media or stock analysts, 'uptrending/trending upwards' is pretty rare. I guess you're right within those domains. Outside those domains it seems an unnecessary neologism.